# Bootstrap navbar brand + justified button, without wrapping on narrow screens?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a very simple Twitter Bootstrap navbar consisting of the navbar brand followed by a justified button filling the remaining navbar width. Unfortunately on some narrow screens (e.g. some phones and browsers) it unnecessarily wraps the button to a 2nd line of navbar while leaving the brand on the first line. There is no need for this - the button should just auto shrink to fill the remaining space, and visually there is plenty.

Any ideas anyone how to force both brand and button to remain on one line of navbar and fill the full width? Code below.

Many thanks.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="topnavdiv">
  <div class="container-fluid" id="navcontainer">
    <div class="navbar-header" id="navbarheader">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" id="navbarbrand">
            <img src="img/logo.png">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="mainnavbar">
        <ul class="nav nav-justified" id="navbuttondiv">
            <li><a href="#" id="navbutton" style="padding-bottom: 15px !important; padding-top: 15px !important;">
                <i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg" style="color: #fff;"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left form-inline nav-justified" style="display: none;"> 
        </form> <!-- Used during a different UI mode but not displayed when the above navbuttondiv is visible -->
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right form-inline" style="display: none;">
        </form> <!-- Used during a different UI mode but not displayed when the above navbuttondiv is visible-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form-horizontal and form-group may help. I'll be able to adjust to your code and test later but wanted to respond as soon as I could. Below is sample code using these classes.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">First Name</label>                        
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Enter First Name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lastname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Last Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Enter Last Name">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Justin I'll try that out